# How to apply solid colors to ggplot lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to print different lines with different colors iwth ggplot2. I dont know why it works when I print my graph with a variable as a color, but when I set a solid color in my eastethics, I get an error

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

The error source is indicated with the comment

```
X3500um_0to50_tx2rx1 X15_30_45_rx2tx2 <- data.frame(
 Time = c(2020-11-03 15:20:00, 2020-11-03 15:20:01), 
 Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2= c(2782, 27804),
 Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx0= c(2782, 27804),
 Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx1= c(2782, 27804),
 Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2= c(2782, 27804))
 

ggplot(X3500um_0to50_tx2rx1, aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +   
  
  geom_line(aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx0)) +   
  geom_line(aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx1, colour = "red")) +   #causes an error??
  geom_line(aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2, colour = Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2))
```

Comment: `aes(colour=Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2)` maps the variable `Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2` to `colour`, meaning that lines with different values of `Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2` will have a different colour and the colour will be determined based on the default palette, unless changed using one of the  `scale_colour_***` functions. If `Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2` is numeric (as it is here), the colour mapping will be on a continuous gradient scale. If you want to hard-code the colour, remove the colour mapping inside `aes` and add `colour="red"` outside `aes`.

Comment: The error is because your trying to map `colour` inside `aes` to a discrete value, but you've already mapped colour to a continuous value in the previous `geom_line` call. If you move the 3rd `geom_line` call above the others (so that it comes first), you'll get the reverse error `Continous value supplied to discrete scale`.

Comment: Chapters 3, 7, and 28 of [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) might be helpful for learning more about how ggplot works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're passing a non-existent variable "red" to the `colour` aesthetic. Aesthetics are essentially the visuals. The syntax for aesthetics is `aes = variable`. The error is generated because you don't have a variable called "red" in your dataframe. `colour = Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2` works because you have a variable called `Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2` in your data, and therefore R automatically assigns colour levels based on the values of this variable. Because your characteristic `red` is global, it should be done outside the `aes`. So, the following code should produce what you're looking for:

```
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages('tidyverse'); library(tidyverse)
if(!require(parsedate)) install.packages('parsedate'); library(parsedate)

X3500um_0to50_tx2rx1 <- data.frame(
  Time = c(parse_iso_8601("2020-11-03T15:20:00"),
           parse_iso_8601("2020-11-03T15:20:01")), 
  Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2= c(2782, 27804),
  Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx0= c(2782, 27804),
  Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx1= c(2782, 27804),
  Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx2= c(2782, 27804))

ggplot(X3500um_0to50_tx2rx1, aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Diff_Touchpad0_Rx1_Tx2)) +   
  geom_line(aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx0)) +   
  geom_line(aes(Time, Diff_Touchpad0_Rx2_Tx1), colour = "red")
```

I'd also recommend the readings suggested by @eipi10.